# Windows C++ Pipe Creates Big Black Terminal Window

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm trying to pipe io through a terminal application as per microsoft's documentation ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682499(VS.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682499%28VS.85%29.aspx)).  The problem is, when I add this code, it pops up a big black empty box / terminal / console window.  I don't want it to do that.

Suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: What child process are you creating? If it's a console app, it comes with a console window...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that the dwFlags member of the STARTUPINFO structure has the STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW bit set and that the wShowWindow is set to SW_HIDE. That should work

Answer (score 0):

You need to padd `CREATE_NO_WINDOW` flag to create process check the [createprocess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425%28VS.85%29.aspx) documentation on creation flags.