# Console Application Console window - Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, console-application

I have made a C++ code in visual studio, a console application. My question is how to make the final exe run without console ( a process only seen from task manager )

The solutions I have seen till now all make the console appear for a second then go out. I don't want this. Don't appear at all.

is there any option or flag in visual studio to do this? ( something like -mwindows flag in g++ )

Thank's in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `Project Properties` on the `Configuration Properties`->`Linker`->`System` page, you need to set the value of `SubSystem` to `Windows (/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS)`. The default for a new console application project is `Console (/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE)`, which causes Windows to allocate a new console or attach to the parent process's console when starting your program.

[image]

---

You also need to change your [`main`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6wd819wh.aspx) function to be [`WinMain`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633559.aspx). The signature for `WinMain is:

```
int CALLBACK WinMain(
  _In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
  _In_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
  _In_ LPSTR     lpCmdLine,
  _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{
    // Your code here
}
```

---

With the above approach, child console processes will still create console windows. Since you stated in a comment that you want to use `popen`, you can't really easily use the normal way of calling `CreateProcess` with `SW_HIDE`.

What you really want to do is to attach a hidden console window to your process and allow your child processes to inherit it. This probably isn't the best code, but here's a way to do it:

```
// Allocates a hidden console window for this process. This console can be
// inherited by child console processes, preventing them from creating a
// visible console. Returns false if the attempt fails.
bool AllocHiddenConsole()
{
  TCHAR command[] = _T("cmd.exe");
  STARTUPINFO startupInfo{};
  PROCESS_INFORMATION processInfo{};
  startupInfo.cb = sizeof(startupInfo);
  startupInfo.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
  startupInfo.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE;

  if (!CreateProcess(NULL, command, NULL, NULL, FALSE,
    CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, NULL, NULL, &startupInfo, &processInfo))
  {
    return false;
  }

  bool attached = false;
  for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
  {
    if (AttachConsole(processInfo.dwProcessId))
    {
      attached = true;
      break;
    }
    Sleep(10);
  }

  TerminateProcess(processInfo.hProcess, 0);
  CloseHandle(processInfo.hProcess);
  CloseHandle(processInfo.hThread);

  return attached;
}
```

Comment: You need to also mention that main() must become WinMain().

Comment: I got WinMain function cannot be overloaded

Comment: @HansPassant: Thanks, I forgot that because I usually do this with C# where the signature of `Main` doesn't change between the various application types.

Comment: This makes many console windows to appear, blink and disappear. They still appear

Comment: Let me guess: Your program starts other programs which are also console applications? That is the only explanation that comes to mind. Without further details on what your program does, I can't determine how to fix it.

Comment: You are right, my code internally deals with windows shell (using popen function ). I think there must be a way to do it, it is done easily in python ( the code also uses popen python function )  and even in G++ with a flag ! how can something like this not found in Visual studio.....

Comment: You are incorrect. Simply running a program which spawns console programs with `pythonw` or using that g++ flag is NOT going to solve the problem of opening child consoles. Those two options do the exact same thing as the change above in Visual Studio (they involve running a program targeting the Windows subsystem). The resulting program will still cause child processes to open a console. You would need to [use `CreateProcess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/procthread/creating-a-child-process-with-redirected-input-and-output) if you want to hide the child window.

Comment: Note: in addition to the article on how to redirect I/O, you would need to [set `wShowWindow` to `SW_HIDE` to also hide the console window.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4005553/2101267)

Comment: My main purpose is "silent run" of the software, according to what you said, what is the best way to do it ?
My software deals heavily with shell internally. It doesn't matter a lot anything except for "silence"

Comment: @MohamedIbrahim, please see the addition to the end of the answer.

Comment: @DarkFalcon Glad with your edit but I have some questions concerning it
I don't understand what will code exactly replace ? does every time I execute a command I will use this ?
Also how to get the response ?

sorry as I am completely new to win32api.

Comment: You call this once before you do anything else. It doesn't replace anything. It is in addition to whatever else you're doing.

Comment: So you mean that using _popen() after calling AllocHiddenConsole() will do the trick ?

Comment: Yes, assuming `AllocHiddenConsole` returns `true`.

Comment: what can make it return false?

Comment: I tried the code in the edit - after removing {} from
  STARTUPINFO startupInfo{};
  PROCESS_INFORMATION processInfo{};
as they give error ! - The console application stops working :D

Comment: I fixed it but unfortunately, cmd blinks then disappear :( 
I used it before using any _popen - directly after wmain. Is there anything I got wrong ?

Comment: You cannot remove the `{}` and  expect it to work the same. That zeros the memory of the structure. If that syntax was not valid, then do it with a call to `ZeroMemory` or `memset`

Comment: I fixed it by making it STARTUPINFO startupInfo= {}, but as  I said, still appears :(

Comment: I want to add that this code worked well when the project itself a win32 application NOT a console application that I changed its subsystem

Comment: Yes, the whole point was that you need to use ALL of the answer for this to work...